# Thymeleaf - custom attribute

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I need to set custom attribute (data-validation-matches-message) value from messages resources.

```
<input data-validation-matches-message="Text from messages resources" />
```

I can receive and print messages resources value as:

```
<p th:text="#{user.notfound}"></p>
```

But how I can set this value for a custom attribute (data-validation-matches-message)?

**UPD** (I use this)

```
<input th:attr="data-validation-matches-message=#{user.notfound}"/>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input th:attr="data-validation-matches-message='\'' + #{user.notfound}" + '\''"/>
```

Comment: This does not work if there are more is more that one custom attribute one wants to add. The other answer is correct.

Comment: There is a single quote missing after the equal-sign: 
th:attr="data-validation-matches-message='\'' + #{user.notfound}" + '\''"

Answer (score 48):

Since Thymeleaf 2.1 you can do this:

```
<a data-th-attr="data-groupid=${somevalue}, data-groupname=${someothervalue}">...</a>
```

[source](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/93)

Answer (score 2):

Using `3.0.9.RELEASE`:

```
<td th:text="${item.description}" th:attr="width=${isSplit} ? '44%' : '59%'" />
```

This will add `width="44%"` or `width="59%`according to a boolean set in the variables.
`width` might as well have been any other custom attribute.