# Can I use Thymeleaf in Polymer Elements with Spring Boot 1.3?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, polymer, thymeleaf, polymer-1.0

I have a spring boot 1.3 web project that uses Polymer 1.2 throughout.  My directory structure looks like:

```
/src/main/java/ (code)
/src/main/resources/static/elements (my Polymer Elements)
/src/main/resources/templates/ (my html templates)
```

I can use Thymeleaf no problem at all in all of my templates, however, I'd like to use it in the Polymer Elements as well.  Is this possible?  If so, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Strange that nobody replied. I just stumbled upon your question. I believe it should be straightfoward. Thymeleaf processes the elements server-side, and as long as valid syntax pops out of it, it should work. One thing to verify would be the custom attributes polymer uses, like "url" in "iron-ajax".

Comment: Custom attributes are possible as by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801158/thymeleaf-custom-attribute